# aws eb cli 3 sets up application for wrong account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, command-line-interface

I have multiple AWS accounts and I'm trying out the new command line interface for elastic beanstalk EB CLI 3.  When I run the following command `eb init` I get prompted for the region (good) and then it asks me to "Select an application to use" where it lists the applications from another AWS account (for staging).  If I go ahead and "Create new application" that application will be created in my staging account.

Is there some way to configure eb cli3 and get it to use different access keys?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can [set up a new profile](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html#cli-multiple-profiles) to use with the EB CLI. Profiles are shared between the AWS CLI and the EB CLI.

Open up your aws config file: `~/.aws/config` and add the following lines:

```
[profile profilename]
aws_access_key_id = aaaaaa
aws_secret_access_key = aaaaaaaaa123
```

Then you can call `eb init --profile profilename`. This will set up the EB CLI to use that specific profile for that specific directory.

Comment: Brilliant, worked perfectly.  I had to also add `region = eu-west-1` to the config file to override the default us region.  Note it's eu-west-1 and not eu-west.  Thanks again

Comment: I think this will work, but it required `eb init --profile <name> --interactive`