# How do I change users in the EB CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli

I deployed an application on EB with my own AWS account, but I need to do the same with another one. I have the user name, access key and secret access key for the AWS account I need to deploy from, but I don't even know how to switch out of my account to do it.

I've been able to sign into the AWS cli with those credentials, but I'm having trouble using the aws elasticbeanstalk cli, so help deploying my application through that would be helpful as well.

Thanks!

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27514937/aws-eb-cli-3-sets-up-application-for-wrong-account

Comment: Are you using the aws combined tool to access elastic beanstalk or the older service specific library.  i.e. are you doing this `aws elasticbeanstalk ....` or  `eb ....`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The AWS CLI credentials are set in credential file and can be overridden with enviroment variables.

To create differnent profiles can use the built in config tool:

```
 aws configure --profile user2
```

Then when you use the aws to call elasticbeanstalk, you can specify this new profile to use

```
aws --profile user2 elasticbeanstalk ...blah...blah...blah...
```

Comment: This is for eb (elastic beanstalk), not elb :/

Comment: @MinaHan here's the reference: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticbeanstalk/index.html

Comment: Ah, I think I get it.

Comment: @Ray The OP is wondering how to do this for the EB CLI not the AWS CLI. That being said, the answers are almost the same.

Comment: @NickHumrich  I'm not sure that's the case--I'll ask for clarification.  Mina mentions using the `aws cli` and the `aws elasticbeanstalk cli` -- I assumed people either use the old service specific tools or the new combined `aws` version not mix, but you may be correct.

Comment: @Ray Elastic beanstalk has their own higher level CLI which is still actively maintained.