# EB CLI init problems... Invalid credentials ERROR: Credential must have exactly 5 slash-delimited elements

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

So I am trying to set up EB CLI and am continually running into the same error. I have done extensive searching and spent several hours now on this and feel like I'm getting no where.

```
Select a default region
1) us-east-1 : US East (N. Virginia)
2) us-west-1 : US West (N. California)
3) us-west-2 : US West (Oregon)
4) eu-west-1 : EU (Ireland)
5) eu-central-1 : EU (Frankfurt)
6) ap-southeast-1 : Asia Pacific (Singapore)
7) ap-southeast-2 : Asia Pacific (Sydney)
8) ap-northeast-1 : Asia Pacific (Tokyo)
9) sa-east-1 : South America (Sao Paulo)

(default is 3): 2
```

(NOTE: My choice here is irrelevant)

```
ERROR: Credential must have exactly 5 slash-delimited elements, e.g. keyid/date/region/service/term, got 'https://917201257127.signin.aws.amazon.com/console/20150708/us-west-2/elasticbeanstalk/aws4_request'
```

How do I edit my credentials? Amazon says I should get some sort of login prompt... Thanks in advance.

Sam

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted?

Answer (score 2):

I have just wasted over an hour on the exact same issue.

Looking back, I think @jordan121sa has a valid solution, but I was looking at the wrong .aws folder, so I'll elaborate on the issue for posterity.

After running `eb init` and selecting a region, I accidentally entered my key and secret in the same prompt and obviously got an error, but a new try at `eb init` would throw the same error again without prompting me for the correct key and secret.

What I make of it is that upon runnning `eb init`, the CLI created a new .aws folder and config file, and it did it a few folders up from where I was looking: `/Users/marsfields/.aws/config` (on a Mac).

I opened the file and it indeed had my mistyped key and secret. Re-entering them correctly and saving the file solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Just delete .config file from C:\Users\VIVEK PATEL.aws>
It will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the aws CLI installed, you can run

```
aws configure
```

Otherwise, your credentials are stored in either ~/.aws/config or ~/.aws/credentials.

You also might want to look [at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27514937/aws-eb-cli-3-sets-up-application-for-wrong-account) for using profiles.

Answer (score 0):

The issue happened to me when I closed my terminal in the middle of setting up eb init. I assume it is corrupting the config file.

The fix that worked for me was simple to remove:

**~/.aws/config**

Then you can set up the credentials again.